How to generate the Typescript declaration files .ts.d from a Node Native Addon (C++)
I have a C function I want to use in a Typescript NodeJS project.
The working minimal project example
I created .CPP file that wraps my C function using N-API and make it available to NodeJS. I created a binding.gyp to compile the Cpp file into a AddLib.node file using node-gyp.
@funvill\add\src\add.cpp
#include <napi.h>
#include <iostream>

int GetNumber() {
    return 5;
}

// Wrappers for the C++ functions
Napi::Value GetNumberWrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    int result = GetNumber();
    return Napi::Number::New(env, result);
}

// Initialization of the addon
Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
    // Example
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "GetNumber"), Napi::Function::New(env, GetNumberWrapped));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(myaddon, Init)

@funvill\add\binding.gyp
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "AddLib",
      'sources': [ 
        'src/add.cpp',
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
      ],
      "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "defines": [ "NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS"],
      "libraries": []
    }
  ]
}

Next, I created an index.ts in the module to create the Typescript declaration files index.ts.d
@funvill\add\src\index.ts
import * as AddLib from "../build/Release/AddLib";
export function GetNumber():number {
  return AddLib.GetNumber();
}

When I build this project I get the following error
src/index.ts:1:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../build/Release/AddLib' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as AddLib from "../build/Release/AddLib";
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 1 error in src/index.ts:1

I think (I could be wrong) this is because there is no Typescript declaration file next to the AddLib.node file in the '../build/Release/' folder.
Question 1: How do I resolve this error?
The module does get built, and I am able to install it in other projects without additional errors.
Question 2: In the @funvill\add\src\index.ts I need to wrap the functions from the native node addon with a Typescript function, so they are exported with Typescript declaration file. This doesn't feel right. Is there a better way?
